# Object of type 'TYPE' is not JSON serializable Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using ReactJS and Graphql as frontend and django and graphene as backend.

In django I have code as follows:

```
company = Company.objects.get(pk=input.company.id)   
###### Result is <Company: Company object (14)>        
UserByManagerCreated.delay(company=company)
```

And in `UserByManagerCreated` I have :

```
@task
def UserByManagerCreated(company):
    #Send emails, ....
    pass
```

But I'm getting an error `Object of type 'Company' is not JSON serializable`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send it to a celery task because it should be serializable, because the delayed task is stored in a queue (`Redis` or `Rabbit`) and it should be serializable. So you can pass all serializable types as arguments to a celery task.

What I suggest is to pass those values that you need to use in the task. Not the `company` itself, but only values you need. Or you can put them into a dictionaty and pass it instead.

```
   company = Company.objects.get(pk=input.company.id)
   company_data = {'id': company.id, 'your_field': company.your_field}   
   UserByManagerCreated.delay(company=company_data)
```

And as AKX advised you can pass only id and retrieve your `company` right in the task. But if it's a sending mail task I think you can send only needed emails list as argument to be sent an email there.

Comment: Or just pass in the ID and retrieve the company object proper in the task.

Comment: `Company.objects.get(pk=input.company.id).values('id', 'name', 'your_field')` will not work because using `.get()` does not return queryset. Without queryset, you can't use `values()`.